# IE 7/8 not appending elements generated in an .each loop

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append, each

In my markup I have this empty `<ul>` to hold my thumbnails: ...

```
<ul class="slideSelectors">
</ul><!--   END ul="slideSelectors" -->
```

... and I’m using jQuery to loop through a bunch of .slide divs and generate the thumbnails: ...

```
// GENERATE THE SLIDE SELECTORS [THUMBNAILS]
$('.slides .slide').each(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var imgTag  = $(this).find('img').parent().html().split('meta"  -->')[1];
    var listItem = '<li><a href="#" title="'+ ID +'">'+imgTag+'</li>';
    //$('.slideSelectors').html(listItem); // loads only last list item, since .html() replaces all previous LIs
    //$('.slideSelectors').add(listItem); // NG in IE7, IE8
    $('.slideSelectors').append(listItem); // NG in IE7, IE8
});
```

... and here’s the trigger business:

```
$('.slideSelectors').on('click', 'li a', function(){
    var selectorIx = parseInt($(this).closest('li').index(), 10);
    newSlide(selectorIx);
});
```

... all of which works a charm in FF, Safari.

IE7/8 however, can’t seem to vibe with .append(): the thumbnail images are rendered (unclickable) but there’s no `<li>` tags and no anchor tags, making the thumbnails useless as selectors. I’ve alerted both the imgTag and listItem variables, which look right (though the image tag is improperly closed, despite being correct in my .slide divs). Same results using .prepend(), and .html() is no good (as I’ve seen suggested in related questions) because I’m in an .each() loop and it renders only the last thumbnail. (I’ve also read elsewhere on SO that this could be related to bad HTML but my code is valid)

This seems to be a known bug but I’ve yet to see a fix. Other than adding another trigger selector, I’m out of ideas. Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution?

Many thanks in advance,

Shecky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
var listItem = '<li><a href="#" title="'+ ID +'">'+imgTag+'</li>';
```

should be

```
var listItem = '<li><a href="#" title="'+ ID +'">'+imgTag+'</a></li>';
```

You missed the closing `</a>` tag, other browsers are smarter than `IE` so it's working but `IE` is not so smart to do that so your thumbnail images are not clickable in `IE`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sheikh, that did it. As an an html veteran, I'm embarrassed to have missed that. I overlooked that because the thumbnails are generated, they aren't in source, otherwise the w3 validator would have given me a heads-up. Cheers!